# Issue solving DFS Flood Fill problem while iterating through branching options

Tags: recursion, dynamic-programming, depth-first-search

I am learning Dynamic Programming and am trying to solve the [Leet Code Flood Fill problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/flood-fill/description/?envType=study-plan&id=algorithm-i).

I came up with this solution, but it doesn't recurse correctly through all the possible moves.

Given the input `image=[[1,1,1],[1,1,0],[1,0,1]]` and `sr=1`, `sc=1`, and `color=2`. I get the incorrect response as `[[2,2,1],[2,2,0],[1,0,1]]`

```
    def floodFill(
        self, image: List[List[int]], sr: int, sc: int, color: int
    ) -> List[List[int]]:
        m = len(image) - 1
        n = len(image[0]) - 1
        basecolor = image[sr][sc]
        self.dfs(image, sr, sc, color, basecolor, m, n)
        return image

    def dfs(self, image, sr, sc, color, basecolor, m, n):
        if sr < 0 or sr > m or sc < 0 or sc > n:
            return
        if image[sr][sc] == color:
            return
        if image[sr][sc] != basecolor:
            return
            
        image[sr][sc] = color
        for direc in [(-1, 0), (0, -1), (1, 0), (0, 1)]:
            sr = sr + direc[0]
            sc = sc + direc[1]
            self.dfs(image, sr, sc, color, basecolor, m, n)
```

But when I update the list in the for loop, I get the right answer `[[2,2,2],[2,2,0],[2,0,1]]`

```
    def floodFill(
        self, image: List[List[int]], sr: int, sc: int, color: int
    ) -> List[List[int]]:
        m = len(image) - 1
        n = len(image[0]) - 1
        basecolor = image[sr][sc]
        self.dfs(image, sr, sc, color, basecolor, m, n)
        return image

    def dfs(self, image, sr, sc, color, basecolor, m, n):
        if sr < 0 or sr > m or sc < 0 or sc > n:
            return
        if image[sr][sc] == color:
            return
        if image[sr][sc] != basecolor:
            return
            
        image[sr][sc] = color
        for direc in [(sr-1, sc), (sr, sc-1), (sr+1, sc), (sr, sc+1)]:
            sr = direc[0]
            sc = direc[1]
            self.dfs(image, sr, sc, color, basecolor, m, n)
```

Can someone explain to me why the values of `sc` or `sc` in the for loop are causing the error? I think it might have something to do with recursion, but can't figure it out. Or maybe it is something really simple that I have overlooked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those loops are not equivalent, they assign `sr` and `sc` with different values.

```py
sr = 1
sc = 1
direcs = [(-1, 0), (0, -1), (1, 0), (0, 1)]
print('directions:', direcs)
for direc in direcs:
    sr = sr + direc[0]
    sc = sc + direc[1]
    print('sr:{} sc:{}'.format(sr, sc))

print('-' * 30)

sr = 1
sc = 1
direcs = [(sr-1, sc), (sr, sc-1), (sr+1, sc), (sr, sc+1)]
print('directions:', direcs)
for direc in direcs:
    sr = direc[0]
    sc = direc[1]
    print('sr:{} sc:{}'.format(sr, sc))
```

Output:

```
directions: [(-1, 0), (0, -1), (1, 0), (0, 1)]
sr:0 sc:1
sr:0 sc:0
sr:1 sc:0
sr:1 sc:1
------------------------------
directions: [(0, 1), (1, 0), (2, 1), (1, 2)]
sr:0 sc:1
sr:1 sc:0
sr:2 sc:1
sr:1 sc:2
```

The first mismatch occurs on a second step:

- In the first version (*(-1,0),**(0, -1)**...* directions) `sr` stays `0` after `sr = sr + direc[0]` since previous `sr` is `0` and current `direc` is `(0,-1)`.
- In the second version (*(sr-1, sc),**(sr, sc-1)**...* directions) `sr` becomes `1` after `sr = direc[0]`. Current `direc` **(1, 0)** was set before the loop has started using an initial `sr` and `sc` values: `(sr, sc-1)`.

As the loop continues discrepancies accumulate or cancel out.